# Is it possible to place two separators in string split() method?

Tags: python, split

Sorry for the lack of better title.

Hopefully the explanation below help.
Given the following string:

```
 f=' Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Movement time\\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 Sleep stage  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14'
```

and are to be split as below

```
' W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 '
' W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 '
' \\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 '
'  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14'
```

To realise this, the following code was drafted

```
f=' Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Movement time\\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 Sleep stage  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14'
raw_hypno = [x for x in f.split('Sleep stage')][1:]
```

which produce the following Output

```
' W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 '
' W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Movement time\\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 '
'  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14'
```

As can be seen, the detail `Movement time` was not properly split.

May I know whether it is possible to assign two `split condition` using the `split` approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex --> `re.split`.

**Ex:**

```
f=' Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Movement time\\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 Sleep stage  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14'
print(re.split(r"Sleep stage|Movement time", f))
```

**Output:**

```
[' ', ' W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 ', ' W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 ', '\\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 ', '  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14']
```

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate it. Wow, this even skip the for loop!

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, unfortunately, I am unable to make this work with a fully function file. I had open a new thread, appreciate if you can provide some thought about it. The thread can be access via https://stackoverflow.com/q/62304903/6446053

Answer (score 1):

You can first replace all the `'Movement time'` into `'Sleep stage'`,

then simply split by `'Sleep stage'`:

```
f=' Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Sleep stage W\\x14\\x00+26070\\x1590\\x14 Movement time\\x14\\x00+28110\\x15120\\x14 Sleep stage  3\\x14\\x00+28230\\x1530\\x14'.replace('Movement time','Sleep stage').split('Sleep stage')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion @Ann, and nice to meet you here, I know are active in the deep learning group of FB.