# Getting the error: expected string or bytes-like object when using re split method

Tags: python, split

This is continuation from the following [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62304425/6446053). While the suggestion by @Rakesh is awesomely compact, but the same solution cannot function properly when used with an open file which is accessible from the [edf_file link](https://physionet.org/content/sleep-edfx/1.0.0/sleep-cassette/SC4002EC-Hypnogram.edf).

The code below

```
file= 'edfx\\SC4002EC-Hypnogram.edf' # Please change according to the location of you file
with open(file, mode='rb') as f:  
    raw_hypno = re.split(r"Sleep stage|Movement time", f)
```

will ouput an error of

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Appreciate for any insight.

Comment: `f` is a *binary* file, you're trying to split it by a `str`. You need to use a binary literal to split: `rb'Sleep ...'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty workaround

Extract the binary and get the string

```
raw_hypno_single = [x for x in str(f.read()).split('Sleep stage',1)][1:]
```

Then, split the sleep stage and movement as suggested in [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62304425/6446053)

```
  raw_hypno =re.split(r"Sleep stage|Movement time", raw_hypno_single[0])
```

The full code is

```
file= 'edfx\\SC4002EC-Hypnogram.edf' # Please change according to the location of you file
with open(file, mode='rb') as f:  
  raw_hypno_single = [x for x in str(f.read()).split('Sleep stage',1)][1:]
  raw_hypno =re.split(r"Sleep stage|Movement time", raw_hypno_single[0])
```